# Simple Flask app for user authentification - error "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm tearing my hair out to find the solution to my problem, which doesn't seem very complicated. I've tried a thousand different ways of modifying my code, but something seems to be eluding me.

I'm trying to make a simple authentication application with flask. Nothing complicated except that I always get this "GET / HTTP/1.1 " 404 error when I launch my app and try to access it via 127.0.0.1:5000.

My folder architecture :

```
project_folder/
│
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── dashboard.html
│
├── run.py
```

my app/**init**.py :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app.config')
```

my app/config.py :

```
SECRET_KEY = 'secrettest'
```

my app/views.py :

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, send_from_directory
import os
from app import app

# Une fonction pour obtenir le chemin du dossier utilisateur
def get_user_folder(username):
    folder_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'user_folders', username)
    return folder_path

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, Faiss Flask!"

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        if username in app.config['FOLDERS'] and password == app.config['FOLDERS'][username]:
            session['username'] = username
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        folder_path = get_user_folder(username)

        if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.makedirs(folder_path)

        files = os.listdir(folder_path)
        return render_template('dashboard.html', files=files)

    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/user_files/<filename>')
def user_files(filename):
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        folder_path = get_user_folder(username)
        return send_from_directory(folder_path, filename)

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

my app/templates/login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/login">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my app/templates/dashboard.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome, {{ session.username }}!</h1>
    <h2>Your Files:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for file in files %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('user_files', filename=file) }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally my run.py:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've tried a lot of things, i understand the issue comes from the routes. But no success.

Thank you very much if you have an hint !

Change routes, tried blueprint with no success

Answer (score 0):

You have all of your routes inside `views.py` but you're not using `views.py` anywhere (you don't show any place where you're importing it or if you're running it).

Refer to [this documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) for a minimal Flask setup